# FullCalendar businessHours from Ajax call

Tags: fullcalendar

I am attempting to set FullCalendar businessHours dynamically.

1. businessHours calls a function -

```
businessHours: getBusinessHours(),
```

2. The function getBusinessHours is constructed as follows (I have added console.log to check what the PHP outputs) -

```
function getBusinessHours(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"../json_business_hours/json_business_hours.php",
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

3. The code for json_business_hours.php -

```
$host     = 'localhost';
$username = '???????';
$password = '?????????????';
$dbname   = '???????????';

$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

if(!$conn)
    {
    die("Cannot connect to the database.". $conn->error);
    }

$bh_sql = "SELECT day_no AS daysOfWeek, day_from AS startTime, day_to AS endTime FROM business_hours WHERE day_closed = 0";

$bh_result = mysqli_query($conn, $bh_sql);
$business_hours = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($bh_result))
    {
        $business_hours[] = $row;
    }
echo json_encode($business_hours);
```

The specified business hours are not applied  and I cannot see why. If I check the console.log output I get -

```
[{"daysOfWeek":[1],"startTime":"09:00:00","endTime":"17:00:00"},
{"daysOfWeek":[2],"startTime":"09:00:00","endTime":"17:00:00"},
{"daysOfWeek":[3],"startTime":"09:00:00","endTime":"17:00:00"},
{"daysOfWeek":[4],"startTime":"09:00:00","endTime":"17:00:00"},
{"daysOfWeek":[5],"startTime":"09:00:00","endTime":"17:00:00"},
{"daysOfWeek":[6],"startTime":"09:00:00","endTime":"13:00:00"}]
```

If I copy the console.log output and paste it in place of the function into my FullCalendar JS -

```
businessHours: [{"daysOfWeek":[1],"startTime":"09:00:00","endTime":"17:00:00"},
                {"daysOfWeek":[2],"startTime":"09:00:00","endTime":"17:00:00"},
                {"daysOfWeek":[3],"startTime":"09:00:00","endTime":"17:00:00"},
                {"daysOfWeek":[4],"startTime":"09:00:00","endTime":"17:00:00"},
                {"daysOfWeek":[5],"startTime":"09:00:00","endTime":"17:00:00"},
                {"daysOfWeek":[6],"startTime":"09:00:00","endTime":"13:00:00"}],
```

The businessHours are applied correctly -

```
[FullCalendar with applied businessHours][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdUHc.png
```

Anyone have any ideas where I'm going wrong? Any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't work because you never actually pass the response from the AJAX call to fullCalendar - and you can't because the AJAX call is async, so by the time the "success" function runs, the businessHours function has already completed and the chance to return anything to the calendar has gone. Fullcalendar doesn't support dynamically setting the businesshours via an async callback in this way (unlike for event feeds, which do support that).

Comment: However you may be able to change the businessHours by calling the `setOption` method - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dynamic-options - when your AJAX call returns. You'd need to do that after the calendar has been initialised though, it won't work by running getBusinessHours() the way you're doing it now, as an option to be set before the calendar is created.

Comment: In the end I solved the problem by running the PHP before loading the calendar. The PHP created an array - $business_hours. This is then used in FullCalendar - businessHours: <?php echo json_encode($business_hours); ?>,

Comment: Yeah that's one way of doing it, assuming you don't need the hours to be updated dynamically once the calendar has already loaded. You should add that as an Answer below, if you solved it :-)

Comment: On deployment each site will have it's own businessHours, so no need to change it dynamically, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I solved the problem by running the PHP before loading the calendar. The PHP created an array - $business_hours. This is then used in FullCalendar - businessHours: ,